# Why can't I use Object.keys() on Set or Map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, set, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use `console.log` to see the properties of a Set object (like `size`). But if I try to log the keys in a Set, I get an empty array:

```
let mySet = new Set();
mySet.add(1);
mySet.add(2);
mySet.add(3);

let keys = Object.keys(mySet);
console.log(keys); 

// Output: []
```

The same thing happens when I use a Map:

```
let myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('1', 1);
myMap.set('2', 2);
myMap.set('3', 3);

let keys = Object.keys(myMap);
console.log(keys); 

// Output: []
```

Comment: Which own enumerable properties does a `Set` have?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect them to be available as keys? The `Set` and `Map` specs never promised it. The keys/values are available using the corresponding APIs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Answer (score 0):

`{Map, Set}.prototype.keys()` has another behavior both returns a new Iterator object not an array with keys:

from [Map MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> `Map.prototype.keys()`
>       Returns a new Iterator object that contains the keys for each element in the Map object in insertion order.

from [Set MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

> `Set.prototype.keys()`
>       Is the same function as the values() function and returns a new Iterator object that contains the values for each element in the Set
>   object in insertion order.